# Java SE RESTful VS java EE

Tags: java, web

I am very confused on what to use in developing a web application. If you can develop a web service using Java se restlet, then why should you bother using Java EE. What are the advantages of the one over the other? When and why should I use each?

Comment: This very much depends on the nature of your application, which you did not explain yet.

Comment: As of now I have no application. Can you give me scenarios from both sides?

Comment: There are no sides; its all Java.

Answer (score 2):

Using something like Restlet doesn't necessary exclude JavaEE (you can use RestLet within JavaEE platforms).

Traditionally, JavaEE containers provide standardized services to applications.  If you wanted to have a way to store your data transactionally, you'd write some EJBs because you didn't have to come up with the transactional model.  The container provided that.  You just focused on the entity and session beans that are specific to your domain.

Spring came along and provided a lot of the same capabilities in its own implementations (sharing some specifications and coming up with their own).  But at the end of the day, you're using a common model for doing stuff.

JavaEE (or Spring) aren't limited to transactional models.  JavaEE incorporates Servlets which in turns supports a raft of Web application frameworks.  But, then again, many applications like tomcat support servlets without supporting the full JavaEE umbrella of specifications.  JavaEE containers can supply JMS servers if your application requires asynchronous messaging, as well as standard means to define JDBC DataSources.

You'd typically use a JavaEE container like Glassfish/JBoss, if you want to have a lot of enterprise-level features without having to set them all up yourself.

You can do all the same things in Spring/etc, which is just a JVM, but you're also setting up all those services yourself (kicking off your own JMS servers, for example).

Historically, JavaEE containers were seen as large, resource-intensive applications which drove a lot of the Springs of the world to piece together just what you want/need.  More modern releases of JavaEE containers are starting to buck that trend, though.

You really need to know what your application wants to do and look at what tools out there will provide you with what you want.  Barring that, just grab Glassfish or something similar and have a play.

Hope this helps.